# how to order seaborn pointplot

Tags: python-3.x, kernel, seaborn, kaggle

Here's code from kaggle Titanic competition [kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/startupsci/titanic-data-science-solutions/notebook):

```
grid = sns.FacetGrid(train_df, row='Embarked', size=2.2, aspect=1.6)
grid.map(sns.pointplot, 'Pclass', 'Survived', 'Sex', palette='deep')
grid.add_legend()
```

It produces wrong plot, the one with reversed colors. I'd like to know how to fix *this exact code fragment*. I tried adding keyword params to grid.map() call - `order=["male", "female"], hue_order=["male", "female"]`, but then plots become empty.

Comment: What do you mean by wrong colors? The colors are correct as far as I can see. Please clearly state what you get as output and what you expect and in how far the two differ.

Comment: Colors were switched in case of Embarked='C' in the original plot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the code call  to `grid.map(sns.pointplot, 'Pclass', 'Survived', 'Sex', palette='deep')`, the x category is the `Pclass` and the hue category is the `Sex`. Hence you need to add

```
order = [1,2,3], hue_order=["male", "female"]
```

Complete example (where I took the titanic that ships with seaborn - what wordplay!):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

grid = sns.FacetGrid(df, row='embarked', size=2.2, aspect=1.6)
grid.map(sns.pointplot, 'pclass', 'survived', 'sex', palette='deep', 
             order=[1,2,3], hue_order=["female","male"])
grid.add_legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that while `hue_order` is definitely required, you may leave out the `order`. While this will throw a warning, the correct order is garantied by the fact that those values are numerical and are hence automatically sorted.

Comment: When I edited the original kernel on kaggle, I found that I had to use the columns with proper casing, otherwise I got a keyError

Comment: @the_interest_seeker This answer uses the dataset which is distributed with seaborn (`sns.load_dataset("titanic")`). This differs from other commonly used datasets by different column names and also some columns might be missing.

Comment: Great answer but I would've +1 only for the pun